# Javascript for sum. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null

Tags: javascript

This is MY pub code

```
for cart, cart_index in cart_collections
table(style='width:100%; margin-bottom:20px;',id="table", border='1')
  tr
    td(style="background:#0077cc; color:#fff")
      strong Cart ID: 
      i #{cart.cart_id}
        for product, product_index in cart.product
          tr 
            td No. #{product_index + 1}
            td Name: #{product.name}
            td Qty: #{product.qty}
            td Price (RM): #{product.price}
            td Pv: #{product.pv}
            td Sub Price (RM): #{product.sub_price}
            td Sub pv: #{product.sub_pv}
            input(
                type="checkbox"
                class="checkbox1"
                id="checkbox1"
                value=`${product.sub_price}`
                onclick="add(this)"
              )
            strong Total Price:RM #{product.sub_price}
          strong Total Amount Need to Pay = RM 
          b(id="val")
```

and my js function

```
    var table = document.getElementById("table"), sumVal = 0;

    for(var i =1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
    sumVal = sumVal + table.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML;
    }

    console.log(sumVal);
```

It show Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null, I have no idea with what wrong on my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your code when the document is ready using the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event. If you run your script in the head of your document, your code may be running before the elements are loaded and thus can not find any elements.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e){
    var table = document.getElementById("table"), sumVal = 0;

    for(var i =1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
    sumVal = sumVal + table.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML;
    }

    console.log(sumVal);
});
```

You can also put a script tag at the bottom of the document before the closing `body` tag to execute the script when all the DOM elements exist.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table">
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
<script>
(function(){
    var table = document.getElementById("table"), sumVal = 0;

    for(var i =1; i < table.rows.length; i++)
    {
    sumVal += +table.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML;
    }

    console.log(sumVal);
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById()` returns `null` whenever it cannot find the element provided by its argument. Ensure element with id `table` exists in the DOM when your script is executed.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('test'));
console.log(document.getElementById('test_wrong'));//bad reference!
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```